# Quarkus + Gradle: How to Reference an Object in subProjectA from subProjectB in a Multi-Project Setup?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, groovy, quarkus

In a non-Quarkus, plain Gradle multi-project setup, I would need to make sure that the `settings.gradle` file of the root project has `include 'subProjectA', 'subProjectB'` and that `subProjectB` build.gradle file has `implementation(project(":subProjectA"))` in its dependencies. This works fine for me.

However, in a multi-project Quarkus Gradle setup, using the exact same approach unfortunately does not work for me.

Here is my file tree (I've removed a lot of the other files for the image to improve clarity of the structure but they are all there).

[image]
Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Build file '/Users/josuegialis/Desktop/MultiQuarkusGradleProject/subProjectB/build.gradle' line: 18

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MultiQuarkusGradleProject'.
> Project with path ':subProjectB' could not be found in root project 'MultiQuarkusGradleProject'.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.`
```

I appreciate any help.

Aside from digging through other questions, I have tried reinstalling/upgrading gradle and intellij. I have also tried to include subprojectA in subProjectB and vice versa. I have created new projects and ensured everything was correct.

Here is the github link to the source code: https://github.com/jgialis1/quarkusmultiprojectdemo

Comment: Can you share the minimal source code without sensitive code to GitHub or Google Drive for me to try to fix it? I think this only invokes Gradle but nothing related to Quarkus.

Comment: it shouldn't matter if it's quarkus or schmarkus multi gradle project. I'd rather say, you have misspelled smth in your gradle configs. Provide them, if you want us to help you fix the problem

Comment: @JackyLiu I added the Github link. Can you please check it out and let me know where my error is? Thanks!

Comment: Also tagging @injecteer

Comment: Why do you have settings.gradle files in the subprojects?

Comment: If I remove them, I get a different error when I try to sync gradle changes: `Task 'prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel' not found in project ':beta'.`

Comment: Oh actually that partially resolved it for me. I was able to delete both files and followed https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/14889#issuecomment-988134777 to resolve that new error.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by ensuring that all subprojects did not have a `settings.gradle` file and in my case, ensuring that IntelliJ did not have multiple sibling projects. So there was only the one parent gradle project and  it contained multiple child subprojects.

See https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/14889#issuecomment-988134777 for more information.